# How to parse data from tbl 1 to tbl 2

Tags: php, mysql

I;m having a problem with parsing the data from table1 into table2
the syntax (INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1) wont work and I dont know why, so i came up with this but still wont work. so what's wrong with my code/query guys?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tempsale")or die(mysql_error());
while($p=mysql_fetch_array($result)){   

if(!empty($p)) {
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tempsale")or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            $prcode = $row[1];
            $pname = $row[2];
            $cname = $row[3];
            $pprice = $row[4];
            $pquan = $row[5];
            $stotal = $row[6];
            $sdate = $row[7];
    }
mysql_query("INSERT INTO sales Values('','".$prcode."', '".$pname."', '".$cname."', '".$pprice."','".$pquan."', '".$stotal."', '".$sdate."','')");

}
}
```

Comment: while using insert into select make sure column number matches. if not then error will occur

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't be using mysql_.  It is deprecated.  Learn mysqli_ or other methods of accessing the database from applications.

Second, this structure should work:

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Why doesn't it work?  Probably because you haven't explicitly put in the column names.  So try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO sales (prcode, pname, cname, pprice, pquan, stotal, sdate)
    SELECT prcode, pname, cname, pprice, pquan, stotal, sdate
    FROM temp_sales;
```

I'm just guessing what the column names are.  Use whatever the correct ones are.